# How to assign AVPlayer play/pause button iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avplayer

I have asked this question before few days but nobody answer me and I could not find the solution.

So I want to ask the same question again and please answer me if you know the answer.

I want to assign these buttons in the picture to my avplayer play/pause button.

[image]

Note: My application icons appear in the now playing bar instead of Music icon, my application works fine in background .

Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

To allow delivery of remote-control events, you must call the [beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents) method of `UIApplication`.

You then respond to the remote control events by implementing the [remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents) method like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] becomeFirstResponder];


    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch (event.subtype)
    {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            // play code
            ...
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            // toggle code
            ...    
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            // next code
            ...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: 
"In iOS 7.1 and later, use the shared [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPRemoteCommandCenter) object to register for remote control events. You do not need to call this method (note: *beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents*)  when using the shared command center object."
([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents))